# No stream value at song number 68973465

Tags: deezer

I have a problem with song 68973465 (in Czech Republic). It is Parov Stelar, Wake Up Sister.
In response is readable = 1, but no stream value. I tested Deezer API for 2 weeks and only this song has this behauvior. JSON response:

```
{
album =     {
   ......
};
artist =     {
  .....
};
bpm = 0;
"disk_number" = 1;
duration = 174;
gain = 0;
id = 68973465;
link = "http://www.deezer.com/track/68973465";
preview = "http://cdn-preview-8.deezer.com/stream/8df01d68a63a746b711200b67a61b12c-0.mp3";
rank = 376784;
readable = 1;
stream = 0;
title = "Wake Up Sister";
"track_position" = 6;
type = track;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug. We're fixing it asap. Thanks for letting us know!
[EDIT] Now fixed.